# Properties of a greatest cluster (limit) point of a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, banach-spaces

I'm currently reading a book **Analysis I**  by Amann and Escher. They define a cluster point of a sequence in a metric space as follows:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. $a \in X$ is a **cluster point** of a sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ if every neighborhood of $a$ contains infinitely many terms of the sequence.

It can be proven the $a$ being a cluster point is equivalent to the following two conditions:

> - For each neighborhood $U$ of $a$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$ there is $n \geq m$ such that $x_n \in U$,
> - for each $\epsilon > 0$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$, there is $n \geq m$ such that $x_n \in B(a,\epsilon)$.

It can be proved that for a sequence $(x_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ which is bounded above, $\overline{\lim} x_n = \lim_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\sup_{k \geq n} x_k$ is the greatest cluster point of the $(x_n)$.

What I don't understand is what property of a greatest cluster point is used in this proof (I only present those parts of the theorem and the proof which a relevant here):

> **Proposition.** Let $\sum x_k$ be a series in a Banach space $(E,||\cdot||)$ and let $\alpha = \overline{\lim} \sqrt[k]{||x_k||}$. If $\alpha < 1$, then $\sum x_k$ converges absolutely.
>
> **Proof.** If $\alpha < 1$, then the interval $(\alpha,1)$ is not empty and we can choose some $q \in (\alpha,1)$. We know that $\alpha$ is the greatest cluster point of the sequence $(\sqrt[k]{||x_k||})$. Hence there is some $K$  such that $\sqrt[k]{||x_k||} < q$ for all $k \geq K$...

I can't see why there would be such $K$. Indeed, for each $m \in \mathbb{N}$ there is $n \geq m$ such that $\sqrt[k]{||x_k||} < \alpha + (q - \alpha) = q$. It's clear that one should somehow use the property of $\alpha$ being the *greatest* cluster point, but I don't see how.

Comment: It is precisely because $\alpha$ is the greatest cluster point that  there is a $K$ such that $k\ge K\Rightarrow \sqrt[k]{||x_k||} < q$ (because $q>\alpha$)

Comment: @Matematleta I see, but it appears we need to take another $\alpha < p < q$ (which we absolutely can). Then $p$ is not a cluster point of $(\sqrt[k]{||x_k||})$ since $\alpha < p$, and so there is $K$ such that for all $k \geq K$ we have $\sqrt[k]{||x_k||} < (q - p) + p = q$. Am I correct? Anyway, thank you, somehow I missed this small detail you mentioned.